# Include screenshots in report test steps with playwright

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

Friends, does anyone have the code that allows me to include the screenshots in the line I want and make this print be attached to the standard playwright report?

I'm using playwright with javascript[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2TEH.jpg)
npx plawright show-report

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **page.screenshot()** to capture the screenshot and use **attach()** to attach the captured screenshto the report like this:

```
  const screenshot = await page.screenshot();
  await testInfo.attach('screenshot', { body: screenshot, contentType: 'image/png' });
```

Comment: The `testinfo` comes from the method arguments. `test('has title', async ({ page }, testinfo) => { ... });`